# Spark driver failure recovery

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to know about how spark restarts the spark driver in case of failure. My understanding is since the driver node is failed, all the computations will be lost, so the restart will mean re-submitting the application. I want to know how driver program is restarted w.r.t to Yarn as resource manager, I know that mesos has a standalone driver node and standalone mode we have --supervise flag but I'm not too sure about yarn. Any explanation will help. The answer I need w.r.t non-streaming application. Sorry for the big question.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48510954/8279585 ; https://stackoverflow.com/q/26618464/8279585

Comment: This is wrt spark streaming